# how to remove "Missing transform attribute error"?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, transform, palantir-foundry

I am writing a code in palantir using pyspark and I have this error which I am unable to figure out.

**The Error is:**

```
A TransformInput object does not have an attribute withColumn. 
Please check the spelling and/or the datatype of the object.
```

**My code for your reference**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
from transforms.api import configure, transform, Input, Output

@transform(
    result = Output('Output_data_file_location'),
    first_input=Input('Input_file1'),
    second_input= Input('Input_file2'),
)
def function_temp(first_input, second_input, result):
    from pyspark.sql.functions import monotonically_increasing_id
    res = ncbs.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())

    # Recode type
    res = res.withColumn("old_col_type", F.when(
        (F.col("col_type") == 'left') | (F.col("col_type") == 'right'), 'turn'
        ).when(
            (F.col("col_type") == 'up') | (F.col("col_type") == 'down'), 'straight'
        ))


    res = res.withColumnRenamed("old_col_type","t_old_col_type") \
    .withColumnRenamed("old_col2_type","t_old_col2_type")


    res = res.filter((res.col_type== 'straight') 


    res = res.join(second_input,  #eqNullSafe is like an equal sign but includes null in join
                (res.col1.eqNullSafe(second_input.pre_col1)) & 
                (res.col2.eqNullSafe(second_input.pre_col2)), 
                how='left')\
                    .drop(*["pre_col1", "pre_col2"]).withColumnRenamed("temp_result", "final_answer")


    result.write_dataframe(res)
```

Can anyone help me with the error. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error code you are receiving explains it pretty well, you are calling `.withColumn()` on an object that is not a regular Spark Dataframe but a `TransformInput` object. You need to call the `.dataframe()` method to access the Dataframe.

The [documentation](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/transforms-python/transforms-pipelines/#transforms) for reference.

In addition you should move the `monotonically_increasing_id` to the top of the file, since Foundrys transform logic level versioning only works when the imports are happening on the module level, according to the documentation.